# Prove $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i) \geq \max_i P(E_i)$ for $n≥1$

Tags: probability

I am having trouble starting this problem. I know trivially, all probabilities are between $0$ and $1$. If $n=1$, $P(E_1)=\max(P(E_1))$ which satisfies the inequality. But when $n=2$, I don't know why $P(E_1 \cup E_2) \geq \max P(E_1, E_2)$ . By definition, $P(E_1 \cup E_2)=P(E_1)+P(E_2) - P(E_1 \cap E_2)$. And intuitively $P(E_1 \cup E_2)\geq P(E_1)$ and $P(E_1 \cup E_2) \geq P(E_2)$ but I don't know how to show this.

Comment: Do you have an axiom that says that if $A\subseteq B$, then $P(A)\le P(B)$? It’s one of the standard axioms. If so, use it with $A=E_1$ and $B=E_1\cup E_2$, and then again with $A=E_2$ and $B=E_1\cup E_2$

Comment: I think I have to prove that as I am only given three axioms:

1) For any event $E\subset \Omega, 0\leq P(E) \leq 1$

2) $P(\Omega)=1$

3) For two mutually exclusive events, $E_1$ and $E_2$, $P(E_1 \cup E_2)=P(E_1)+P(E_2)$.

Comment: Okay. You can write $E_1\cup E_2$ as the union of the mutually exclusive events $E_1$ and $E_2\setminus E_1$ and use the fact that $P(E_1\setminus E_2)\ge 0$.

Comment: So $P(E_1 \cup E_2)=P(E_1 \cup (E_2 \cap E_1^c))=P(E_1)+P(E_2 \cap E_1^c)$ 

And similarly,
$P(E_1 \cup E_2)=P(E_2 \cup (E_1 \cap E_2^c))=P(E_2)+P(E_1 \cap E_2^c)$ ???

Comment: Yes, and similarly with $E_1$ and $E_2$ interchanged.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott which implies $P(E_1 \cup E_2)≥P(E_1)$ and $P(E_2)$ since $P(E_1 \cap E_2^c) \geq 0$ and $P(E_2 \cap E_1^c) \geq 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. And you can use the same idea (with $A$ and $B\cap A^c$) to get the general result that I mentioned in my first comment.

Answer (score 3):

Since $E_k \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i$, we have $P(E_k) \le P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i)$ for all $k$. Hence
$\max_k P(E_k) \le P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i)$.

**Note**: To see why the first statement is true, write
$\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i = E_k \cup ((\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i) \setminus E_k)$. Since
$E_k$ and $(\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i) \setminus E_k$ are disjoint, we have
$P( \bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i)= P(E_k)+P((\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i) \setminus E_k)$, and
since $P((\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i) \setminus E_k) \ge 0$, we have the desired inequality.